# Save current date in database

Tags: angularjs

so i have an entity in which i want to put the current date while saving a form, without inputs for that date.

```html
    <tr>
         <td> Emise aujourdh'hui le : </td>
         <td > {{dateEmission | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
         </tr>
```

and the js is  :

```js
//Get current date
$scope.dateEmission = new Date();

//save demande
$scope.savedemande = function() {
  $http.post("/createDemande", $scope.demande).success(function(data) {
   if (!data.errors) {
    $scope.demande=data;
    $scope.errors = null;
  }

   else {

   }

  })
  .error(function(data) {
   $scope.exception.message=data.message;
   
  });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to pass `dateEmission` to the server with the `POST` request, is it? the key, `dateEmission` doesnt seem to be part of `$scope.demande`. How about:

```
 $scope.savedemande = function() {
            var today=new Date();
            var date= today.toLocaleDateString() + today.toLocaleTimeString();
            $scope.demande.dateEmission=date;
            $http.post("/createDemande", $scope.demande).success(function(data) {
                if (!data.errors) {
                    $scope.demande=data;
                    $scope.errors = null;
            }

                else {

                }

            })
            .error(function(data) {
                $scope.exception.message=data.message;

            });
        };
```

Comment: How to make it a part of it ?

Comment: i assume `$scope.demande` is an object? So just say `$scope.demande.date